# How to use base64 encode in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64

So I wanted to have email confirmation and stuff on page but putting userid as parameter is not the best idea so I tried to encode this in base64, but I am dumb and something went wrong and even though I don't get any errors, my base64 encoded string looks like this:
*AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA*(Here's proof: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh9gH.png)),
I get Deprecation warning: `(node:32320) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.`, and for no reason my db doesn't get new account.
Here's encode

```js
app.get('/account/email_confirmation', async (req, res) => {
  let temporary_user_id = req.session.temporary_user_id;
  let buffer = new Buffer(temporary_user_id);
  let base64 = buffer.toString('base64');
  console.log(temporary_user_id, base64);
  let email = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL,
    to: req.session.email,
    subject: 'Your .whiteboard account confirmation',
    text: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirm/${base64}`
  };
  transporter.sendMail(email, async (err, info) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(info.response);
    let theme = await get_theme(req)
    res.render('send_email', {theme: theme})
  })
})
```

And here's decode:

```js
app.get('/confirm/:userID', async (req,res) => {
  let userID = req.params.userID;
  let buffer = new Buffer(userID, 'base64');
  let str = buffer.toString('ascii');
  let query = "SELECT verified FROM verified WHERE id = ?;";
  con.query(query, [str], async (err, result) => {
    console.log('aaaaaaaaaaaa')
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(result[0].verified);
    if(result[0].verified == 0){
      console.log('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb')
      query = 'UPDATE verified SET verified = 1 WHERE id = ?'
      let theme = await get_theme(req);
      con.query(query, [str], (err) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render('confirm', {theme: theme});
      })
    }else{
      res.redirect('/account/login');
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: what's the output of `console.log(temporary_user_id)`?

Comment: Number higher than 1

Answer (score 5):

so first of all you have used **new Buffer** which is already deprecated, so i suggest you to use this.

```
 const base64data = Buffer.from('someText').toString('base64')
```

and to decode it just use

```
Buffer.from(base64data, 'base64').toString('ascii')
```

As far as it goes to your code, its not wrong base64 conversion is right, may be there can be issue in your **temporary_user_id**, because of that you are getting some awkward text but conversion is done right afaik.

Just do this and it will solve the issue.

```
JSON.stringify(temporary_user_id)
```

The way you are telling error is because it expect a string so you have to convert it to a string. This will solve your issue.

Comment: (1) `new Buffer(temporary_user_id)` returns 'AAAA...' because if you call `new Buffer(6)`, it creates a new (empty) buffer _of that length_. 000000 (all zeros, b/c its empty) encodes to 'AAAAAAAA'. (2) You can store numbers in buffers, not just strings: `const buf = Buffer.alloc(8); buf.writeDoubleBE(temporary_user_id); buf.toString('base64')` & read with `Buffer.from(str, 'base64').readDoubleBE()` (there's also `writeUInt32` and more, depending on your needs)

Comment: I hope my answer helped you a bit.

Comment: Is there any reason why to use `ascii` instead of `utf-8` when decoding?

Comment: @EJMason, no reasons. We can use `utf-8` too.